# How to check if one of the field of the document exist in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

This function is used to update like in multiple collection of the database. The code below is the function but it return error 500.

Database structure
posts (collection) -> id (doc) -> likes (collection) and likesCount (field)

I need to check whether there is likes collection exist so that I can create a document for likes collections if it does not exist and likesCount field should be updated to 1.

I wish to know whether I can also update different collection at the same time for users collection and publicPosts collection. The fields also is required to be checked like the function below.

```
exports.updateLike = function (req, res) {

    const postId = req.params.postId;   
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    let postRef = db.collection("post").doc(postId)

    postRef.collection("likes").doc(userId).get().then( doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            throw new Error("User already like the posts!")
        } else {
            postRef.collection("likes").doc(userId).set({
                uid: userId,
                createAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
            })
            //postRef.get().then( doc => {
            //})
            console.log("--- Operation Success ---")
            return res.status(200).json({ "message" : "success" });
        }

    }).catch(err => { 
        console.log("--- Operation Failure ---")
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: What is the `err` when you send back `res.status(500)`?

Comment: It state internal server error on postman but on the firebase console it did not state the error. only printed ```--- Operation Failure ---```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the mistake which causing the status 500 to appear.

I change from

```
if(doc.exists)
```

to

```
if(!doc.exists)
```